# Iterate over both text and elements in lxml etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

Suppose I have the following XML document:

```
<species>
    Mammals: <dog/> <cat/>
    Reptiles: <snake/> <turtle/>
    Birds: <seagull/> <owl/>
</species>
```

Then I get the `species` element like this:

```
import lxml.etree
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
species = doc.xpath('/species')[0]
```

Now I would like to print a list of animals grouped by species. How could I do it using ElementTree API?

Comment: if you look over to your right ... it looks like the 4th one down under related should point you in the right direction ...

Comment: do you have control of the xml format? Normally, classifiers such as Mammals, etc, are expressed as xml element names or attributes (e.g, <species flavor="Mammals">) so that xpath selectors are easily written.

Comment: No, I can't change the XML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you enumerate all of the nodes, you'll see a text node with the class followed by element nodes with the species:

```
>>> for node in species.xpath("child::node()"):
...     print type(node), node
... 
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> 
    Mammals: 
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'> <Element dog at 0xe0b3c0>
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>  
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'> <Element cat at 0xe0b410>
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> 
    Reptiles: 
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'> <Element snake at 0xe0b460>
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>  
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'> <Element turtle at 0xe0b4b0>
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'> 
    Birds: 
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'> <Element seagull at 0xe0b500>
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>  
<type 'lxml.etree._Element'> <Element owl at 0xe0b550>
<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>
```

So you can build it from there:

```
my_species = {}
current_class = None
for node in species.xpath("child::node()"):
    if isinstance(node, lxml.etree._ElementStringResult):
        text = node.strip(' \n\t:')
        if text:
            current_class = my_species.setdefault(text, [])
    elif isinstance(node, lxml.etree._Element):
        if current_class is not None:
            current_class.append(node.tag)
print my_species
```

results in

```
{'Mammals': ['dog', 'cat'], 'Reptiles': ['snake', 'turtle'], 'Birds': ['seagull', 'owl']}
```

This is all fragile... small changes in how the text nodes are arranged can mess up the parsing.

Comment: I like this one, simple XPath :)

Comment: @alecxe - you process an ever increasing number of previous text nodes and discard all but the last one each time... I think my solution is simpler.

Comment: In Python 3, text node's type is `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult`.

Comment: You could also use `hasattr(node, 'text')`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! BTW if you are building on @Alicia's example, you could/should actually use the `docs` variable instead of `species` since it's not needed for what you are doing.

Answer (score 7):

## Design note

The answer by @tdelaney is basically right, but I want to point to one nuance of Python element tree API. Here's a quote from [the `lxml` tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text):

> Elements can contain text:
>
> ```
> <root>TEXT</root>
> ```
>
> In many XML documents (data-centric documents), this is the only place where text can be found. It is encapsulated by a leaf tag at the very bottom of the tree hierarchy.
>
> However, if XML is used for tagged text documents such as (X)HTML, text can also appear between different elements, right in the middle of the tree:
>
> ```
> <html><body>Hello<br/>World</body></html>
> ```
>
> Here, the `<br/>` tag is surrounded by text. This is often referred to as document-style or mixed-content XML. Elements support this through their `tail` property. It contains the text that directly follows the element, up to the next element in the XML tree.
>
> The two properties `text` and `tail` are enough to represent any text content in an XML document. This way, the ElementTree API **does not require any special text nodes in addition to the Element class**, that tend to get in the way fairly often (as you might know from classic DOM APIs).

## Implementation

Taking these properties into account it is possible to retrieve document text without forcing the tree to output text nodes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3


import itertools
from pprint import pprint

try:
  from lxml import etree
except ImportError:
  from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
  
  
def textAndElement(node):
  '''In py33+ recursive generators are easy'''

  yield node

  text = node.text.strip() if node.text else None
  if text:
    yield text

  for child in node:
    yield from textAndElement(child)

  tail = node.tail.strip() if node.tail else None
  if tail:
    yield tail
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
  xml = '''
    <species>
      Mammals: <dog/> <cat/>
      Reptiles: <snake/> <turtle/>
      Birds: <seagull/> <owl/>
    </species>
  '''
  doc = etree.fromstring(xml)
  
  pprint(list(textAndElement(doc)))
  #[<Element species at 0x7f2c538727d0>,
  #'Mammals:',
  #<Element dog at 0x7f2c538728c0>,
  #<Element cat at 0x7f2c53872910>,
  #'Reptiles:',
  #<Element snake at 0x7f2c53872960>,
  #<Element turtle at 0x7f2c538729b0>,
  #'Birds:',
  #<Element seagull at 0x7f2c53872a00>,
  #<Element owl at 0x7f2c53872a50>]
  
  gen = textAndElement(doc)
  next(gen) # skip root
  groups = []
  for _, g in itertools.groupby(gen, type):
    groups.append(tuple(g))
  
  pprint(dict(zip(*[iter(groups)] * 2)) )
  #{('Birds:',): (<Element seagull at 0x7fc37f38aaa0>,
  #               <Element owl at 0x7fc37f38a820>),
  #('Mammals:',): (<Element dog at 0x7fc37f38a960>,
  #                <Element cat at 0x7fc37f38a9b0>),
  #('Reptiles:',): (<Element snake at 0x7fc37f38aa00>,
  #                <Element turtle at 0x7fc37f38aa50>)}
```